# xcoffins – problem "reusing" poles after joining coffins

Tags: xcoffins

at the moment I'm working on a personal project where I want to use several grids and I thought it would be nice trying `xcoffins` to realise this. I can define a coffin for the text body, define poles for the grid and join ONE additional coffin wherever I want to. But when joining a second coffin, I always get the error "pole does not exist". It doesn't matter if I use the normal join or the starred version, or if I use `[\BodyGrid-PoleColC, ...]`, only redefining the poles works. As this is quite exhausting (I could easier use offsets) I would like to ask if I misunderstood the implementation of poles and should use a different approach.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{scrbook}%

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}%
\pagestyle{empty}%
\usepackage[width=176mm,height=250mm,left=19mm,top=19mm]{geometry}%
\usepackage{xcolor,xcoffins}%

\begin{document}%

\NewCoffin \BodyGrid%
\SetVerticalCoffin \BodyGrid {176mm} {\color{green!10!white}\rule{176mm}{236mm}}%

\SetVerticalPole \BodyGrid {PoleColA} {0mm}%
\SetVerticalPole \BodyGrid {PoleColB} {30mm}%
\SetVerticalPole \BodyGrid {PoleColC} {60mm}%
\SetVerticalPole \BodyGrid {PoleColD} {90mm}%
\SetVerticalPole \BodyGrid {PoleColE} {120mm}%
\SetVerticalPole \BodyGrid {PoleColF} {150mm}%

\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowA} {236mm}%
\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowB} {206mm}%
\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowC} {176mm}%
\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowD} {146mm}%
\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowE} {116mm}%
\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowF} {86mm}%
\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowG} {56mm}%
\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowH} {26mm}%

\NewCoffin \CoffinFC%
\SetVerticalCoffin \CoffinFC {26mm} {\rule{26mm}{26mm}}%
\JoinCoffins \BodyGrid [PoleColF,PoleRowC] \CoffinFC [l,t]%

\SetVerticalPole \BodyGrid {PoleColA} {0mm}%
\SetVerticalPole \BodyGrid {PoleColB} {30mm}%
\SetVerticalPole \BodyGrid {PoleColC} {60mm}%
\SetVerticalPole \BodyGrid {PoleColD} {90mm}%
\SetVerticalPole \BodyGrid {PoleColE} {120mm}%
\SetVerticalPole \BodyGrid {PoleColF} {150mm}%

\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowA} {236mm}%
\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowB} {206mm}%
\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowC} {176mm}%
\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowD} {146mm}%
\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowE} {116mm}%
\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowF} {86mm}%
\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowG} {56mm}%
\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowH} {26mm}%

\NewCoffin \CoffinCG%
\SetVerticalCoffin \CoffinCG {26mm} {\rule{26mm}{26mm}}%
\JoinCoffins \BodyGrid [PoleColC,PoleRowG] \CoffinCG [l,t] %

\TypesetCoffin \BodyGrid%

\end{document}%
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  If I knew more about your underlying problem, I might suggest an alternative using `stackengine`.

Comment: Hi Steven, in my opinion (as a layperson) the problem is, that the definied poles get lost after a join. And probably it is not intended to repeat the pole definition every time I use a join. Of course I can define a function for pole setting, and include it in a function for coffin setting ... but is this the way it should be? Jens

Comment: Sorry I can't offer more help.  Still squeamish about working with something called "coffins".  Don't want to earn the "undertaker" moniker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a join or attach operation, the poles of the original coffins are kept as `\<coffin name>-<pole name>`, so that possibly duplicate poles are not overwritten. You can see that by examining the coffin structure using `\ShowCoffinStructure \BodyGrid`.

Note, for example, that if you compare the output of `\ShowCoffinStructure` after the first `\JoinCoffins` (joining `\BodyGrid` with `\CoffinFC`), and after the second `\JoinCoffins` (joining `\BodyGrid+\CoffinFC` with `\CoffinCG`), you'll see the poles `\CoffinCG-...` added to the structure. Also, if you join `\CoffinCG` in a way that displaces `\BodyGrid+\CoffinFC`, like:

```latex
\JoinCoffins \BodyGrid [\BodyGrid-l,\BodyGrid-T] \CoffinCG [r,B] %
```

then all the poles of the original `\BodyGrid` and `\CoffinFC` coffins are updated (inside `\BodyGrid`, of course) to match the new position of the entire thing.

The following code produces the same typeset output as yours. I just removed the second bunch of poles you added, and in the second join operation I changed:

```latex
\JoinCoffins \BodyGrid [PoleColC,PoleRowG] \CoffinCG [l,t] %
```

to

```latex
\JoinCoffins \BodyGrid [\BodyGrid-PoleColC,\BodyGrid-PoleRowG] \CoffinCG [l,t] %
```

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{scrbook}%

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}%
\pagestyle{empty}%
\usepackage[width=176mm,height=250mm,left=19mm,top=19mm]{geometry}%
\usepackage{xcolor,xcoffins}%

\begin{document}%

\NewCoffin \BodyGrid%
\SetVerticalCoffin \BodyGrid {176mm} {\color{green!10!white}\rule{176mm}{236mm}}%

\SetVerticalPole \BodyGrid {PoleColA} {0mm}%
\SetVerticalPole \BodyGrid {PoleColB} {30mm}%
\SetVerticalPole \BodyGrid {PoleColC} {60mm}%
\SetVerticalPole \BodyGrid {PoleColD} {90mm}%
\SetVerticalPole \BodyGrid {PoleColE} {120mm}%
\SetVerticalPole \BodyGrid {PoleColF} {150mm}%

\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowA} {236mm}%
\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowB} {206mm}%
\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowC} {176mm}%
\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowD} {146mm}%
\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowE} {116mm}%
\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowF} {86mm}%
\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowG} {56mm}%
\SetHorizontalPole \BodyGrid {PoleRowH} {26mm}%

\NewCoffin \CoffinFC%
\SetVerticalCoffin \CoffinFC {26mm} {\rule{26mm}{26mm}}%
\JoinCoffins \BodyGrid [PoleColF,PoleRowC] \CoffinFC [l,t]%

% \ShowCoffinStructure \BodyGrid %

\NewCoffin \CoffinCG%
\SetVerticalCoffin \CoffinCG {26mm} {\rule{26mm}{26mm}}%
\JoinCoffins \BodyGrid [\BodyGrid-PoleColC,\BodyGrid-PoleRowG] \CoffinCG [l,t] %

% \ShowCoffinStructure \BodyGrid %

\TypesetCoffin \BodyGrid%

\end{document}%
```

Comment: Thanks Phelype! This is the solution.

Comment: I tried \BodyGrid-PoleColC ... but I did it for the first AND second coffin. Now I realize that at the first time they don't exist yet.

Comment: @Jensolig Yeah, when you first define a coffin only the one- or two-letter standard names exist. `\ShowCoffinStructure` helps a lot when debugging these. Also, some time ago there was a discussion [here](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/158) about the pole-renaming thing, suggesting that only standard pole names should be renamed. If you, as a user, have an idea about that, feel free to comment there.